# Discord.js ReferenceError: channel is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using the discordjs bot guide and copied their help command from the GitHub. However the code gives an error. I've tried almost every solution I could find for the ReferenceError I'm getting. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```js
const { prefix } = require('../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
    aliases: ['commands'],
    usage: '[command name]',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args) {
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        if (!args.length) {
            data.push('Here\'s a list of all my commands:');
            data.push(commands.map(command => command.name).join(', '));
            data.push(`\nYou can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);

            return message.author.send(data, { split: true })
                .then(() => {
                    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                    message.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                    message.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you!');
                });
        }

        const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

        if (!command) {
            return message.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
        }

        data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

        if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
        if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
        if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);

        data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`);

        message.channel.send(data, { split: true });
    },
};
```

The error:

```
ReferenceError: channel is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\commands\utility\help.js:64:5)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\index.js:78:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)        
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\JS Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: please post your config.json

Comment: @Luiz

{
 "prefix": "!",
 "token": "token"
}

Comment: where do you reference the channel? the error you are getting is that the channel is not defined

Comment: @Luiz I am not sure if I even do, but the exact same command used to work like it is written now. It just... doesn't anymore. It's also directly from the guide repo itself. https://github.com/discordjs/guide/tree/master/code-samples/command-handling/adding-features/12

Comment: What have you done before it stoped worked?

Comment: @Luiz I tried to make it an embed instead of a plain message. It started throwing this exact error then. When undoing it with ctrl + z, the original code also stopped working

Comment: The code you posted on this question is only having 46 lines, however the eror are on line 64. Would you edit the question with more details @Feesh ? Thanks !